# Can CF_RETURNS_RETAINED be used on C function pointer return values bridged to Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, clang, llvm, core-foundation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_core_foundation_types

If we define a C function that returns a CFType, Swift can (sometimes) bridge the memory management semantics. If Swift cannot bridge the memory management semantics, we can end up with an Unmanaged type:

```objectivec
CFStringRef CreateStringByAddingTwoStrings(CFStringRef s1, CFStringRef s2);
```

bridges to:

```swift
public func CreateStringByAddingTwoStrings(_ s1: CFString!, _ s2: CFString!) -> Unmanaged<CFString>!
```

We can improve the bridging with the CF_RETURNS_RETAINED annotation:

```objectivec
CFStringRef CreateStringByAddingTwoStrings(CFStringRef s1, CFStringRef s2) CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

now bridges to:

```swift
public func CreateStringByAddingTwoStrings(_ s1: CFString!, _ s2: CFString!) -> CFString!
```

Alternatively, we can use the `CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED` macro on this function:

```objectivec
CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED

CFStringRef CreateStringByAddingTwoStrings(CFStringRef s1, CFStringRef s2);

CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED
```

What does not seem to be documented is how to improve bridging when function pointer return values should be annotated. For example:

```objectivec
typedef CFStringRef (*CreateStringByAddingTwoStrings)(CFStringRef, CFStringRef);
```

bridges to:

```swift
public typealias CreateStringByAddingTwoStrings = @convention(c) (CFString?, CFString?) -> Unmanaged<CFString>?
```

Is there any way to annotate the function pointer to properly communicate the memory management semantics? Adding the `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` and `CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED` macros do not seem to help.

Comment: I would guess that if such a thing existed, it would be used with the CF callbacks for things like the CFAllocator (e.g. `CFAllocatorCopyDescriptionCallBack`).  They return the `Unmanaged` types too.